# Google Bar Chart API Configuration (Vertical Line)

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, google-visualization

I want to configure and draw a vertical line over the Google chart e.g. - [link](http://goalmgmt.com/uc/img/acadamicBalance.png);

Here is the Google chart I want to configure - [link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart);

Thank you in advance

-Nasir

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Bar chart use column chart. This should help you out.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart

Comment: But my client needs as I explained!